# Cannot find gtkmm.h

Tags: redhat, gtkmm

I have been asked to port a Linux C++ application to 64-bit RedHat 6.2. Instructions for buildling the application indicate that GTK+ (gtkmm24-2.8.0 or greater) and GLADE (libglademm24-2.6.1 or greater) are required. I successfully ran: **aclocal**, **automake** and **./configure** but when I run **make**, I get:

```
error: gtkmm.h No such file or directory
```

I could not find gtkmm.h anywhere in the file system. I used **yum** to search for gtkmm and it found **gtkmm24.x86_64** which I installed but it did not install gtkmm.h. Does anyone know how I can get the header files for gtkmm for 64-bit RedHat 6.2?

Comment: On debian systems, development packages of libraries are usually seperate from runtime packages.  If redhat is the same, you should be able to find a development version of gtkmm that can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install gtkmm24-devel. After that you'll be able to use

```
pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-2.4
```

to get the list of include directories needed for using gtkmm.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to install gtkmm24-devel?

Comment: yum tells me that gtkmm24-devel is not available. yum search gtkmm24 only finds gtkmm24.x86_64 and after installaion, gtkmm.h is not present.